# Using execl to copy two files provided when calling the executable

Tags: c, process, operating-system, command, exec

My executable is named `copy`.

I want when executing

```
copy file1 file2
```

to basically do

```
cp -i -p file1 file2
```

And I want to accomplish this using the `execl` function.

Now I have more expertise with the `execvp` that automatically searches for the path of the command.

So I can do something like the following:

```
char *cmd[] = {"cp","-ip",0}
execvp(cmd[0],cmd);
```

But how can I even using `execvp` to specify the `argv[1]` which is file1 and `argv[2]` which is file2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the prototype of the execl function:

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...
                       /* (char  *) NULL */);
```

So it take in parameters the path to the binary, and then the arguments.
The binary you want to use is cp, so, the path will be /bin/cp (you can use *whereis cp* to find the binary location).

And then you juste have to pass the arguments needed by cp.
Like this for exemple:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  execl("/bin/cp", "-i", "-p", argv[1], argv[2], (char *)0);
}
```

To have the cp interactive prompt, you have to call cp from a shell. To simulate this you can call your command with sh. You can use directly the [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function, or use the functions from the execl family.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *cmd;
  if (asprintf(&cmd, "cp -ip %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]) == -1)
    return (1);
  execlp("sh", "sh", "-c" , cmd, (char *)0);
}
```

Comment: can you combine -i and -p into -ip ??

Comment: Yes, you juste provide arguments like in your unix shell. Juste remove the "-p" in my exemple, and modify "-i" to be "-ip".
And it's the same with execvp, just put the args inside a char *[].
char *cmd[] = {"-ip", argv[1], argv[2], (char *)0};

Comment: I have 

 char *copy[] = {"/bin/cp","-i","-p"};
  execl(copy[0],copy[1],copy[2],argv[1],argv[2],(char *) 0);

Comment: but it doesn't seem to prompt me for over writing, like -i is not working , do u know why @Louis

Comment: It may be due to the fact that you're not executing it from a tty. So it doesn't display a prompt. But it's just an hypothesis.

Comment: I updated my post with a solution. Don't know if it's the good method but it works :)